# MSSQL get INSERTED ID and return it with string PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Hello I have working mssql php insert codes but i want to get inserted id return with string ($newid) My codes under.

**OrderId = int and Primary Key not null**

```
$querysf = "SELECT TOP 1 OrderId FROM Orders ORDER BY OrderId DESC";
$resultsf = mssql_query($querysf);

//Getting manually latest OrderId but this is not good :(

while($rowsf = mssql_fetch_array($resultsf))
{
    $newid = $rowsf["OrderId"];
    $newid = $newid + 1;

    echo("$newid"); //Getting manually latest OrderId but this is not good :( Some one can easily take this id and will be mistakes

    $mydate = date("Y-m-d");

    $ready = mssql_fetch_assoc(mssql_query("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Orders ON; SELECT CONVERT(NCHAR(100),NEWID()) as Ok"));

    $queryer = mssql_query("INSERT INTO Orders (OrderId, CustomerId, DeliveryDate, OrderState,Signature,UserName,special_field,rowguid) VALUES ('$newid', '$CustomerId', '$mydate 00:00:00.000', '1',NULL,'$UserName',NULL,'".$ready['Ok']."')"); 

    $close = mssql_fetch_assoc(mssql_query("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Orders OFF;"));

}
```

Comment: You can't really generate an integer key outside the database.  But you could generate a GUID (http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php).  If you don't want to change data types you could look into using the OUTPUT clause (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) to capture the generated id.

Comment: set order_id to auto increment, insert without any value for order_id and use mysql_insert_id to get the generated ID. Your code can fail if 2 users place orders at the same time. Also consider upgrading to php 5.5 using pdo or mysqli

Comment: @VictorRadu - destination-data ; yeah good comments dudes but any idea without auto increment ?

Comment: without auto increment your only good option is locking the table after read and unlocking after update http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html but I would really recommend that all your tables have a auto increment